# How to consume Server Sent Events(SSE) in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, database, express, server-sent-events

I'm getting Server Sent Events from a particular source but, I don't want to consume them directly in a browser (Client) instead, I'd like to consume those events in a server (NodeJS) and modify those event data and store the modified data in a database.

I have tried using **eventsource** node module but I couldn't achieve what I wanted...
Below depicted is the flow I want to achieve.

SSE events from third party ===> NodeJS server (*consume them, modify them, store them into a DB*) ====> (*serve to the client*) Client (any browser)

Any ideas!!!

Comment: did you find a solution to this?